# Julia append!() Cannot `convert` an object of type Char to an object of type String

Tags: julia

I'm trying to add a String to an array, as follows:

```
arry = String[]
append!(arry, "test")
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot `convert` an object of type Char to an object of type String
```

Why am I getting this error when I'm adding a String, not a Char?

(posting my own answer below for the benefit of other Julia newbies - anyone with more helpful tips please jump in!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot see your answer, but here is a typical pattern.

You can `push!` a single element or `append!` a collection:

```
julia> arry = String[]
0-element Array{String,1}

julia> push!(arry, "test")
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "test"

julia> append!(arry, ("test",))
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "test"
 "test"

julia> append!(arry, ["test"])
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "test"
 "test"
 "test"

julia> append!(arry, Ref("test"))
4-element Array{String,1}:
 "test"
 "test"
 "test"
 "test"
```

Note that a collection can be e.g. a `Tuple`, a `Vector` or `Ref` (which is kind of 0-dimensional and non-allocating collection that is often encountered in broadcasting).

Comment: Dang you were fast! Went for a coffee break before I posted this and you already were on it!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `push!()`, not `append!()`.

`append!()` always treats its argument as an iterator, whereas `push()!` treats the argument as a single object to get added as an intact unit. Since Julia Strings are iterators (where each character is iterated as a `Char`), your "test" string is iterated Char by Char. Since you specified your array as String type, Julia performs type checking on objects you insert into the array; that's why you got the error.

For those coming from Python, Julia's `push!()` is the closer equivalent to Python's `append()`.

So, here is how the behavior differs between the two functions on an Any array (which basically allows any type to be added):

```
# using append!():
arry = Any["a"]
append!(arry, "test")
# result == ["a", 't', 'e', 's', 't'] (a String and four Chars)

# using push!():
arry = Any["a"]
push!(arry, "test")
# result == ["a", "test"] (two Strings)
```